# Unknown labels for mmdetection

Tags: python, label, detection

I used mmdetecion pretrained model on my own dataset. I ran the image_demo.py. In the predictions, I do not know what label numbers correspond to which bounding box. How do I find it, is there a way to find it or will I need to re-run the code after labeling?

Comment: Usually in the config file that you use, you have to set `num_classes` and `meta_info`.

But you need to train the model first to know which bounding boxes are from which label. If you just use the pretrained model where the classes are different than your dataset, there is no way to do it as no association exists,